# Список установленных программ

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Как в Андроид вывести в `ListView` список установленных программ?

Откуда его взять?

Нужно вычислить: установлено ли нужное приложение или нет (по названию приложения или пакета).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот несколько способов:

- :

  ```
  public class AppList extends Activity {
                   private ListView lView;
                   private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();

                   @Override
                   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                    lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
                    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,
  null);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

                    List<ResolveInfo> list =
  pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,
              PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
                     results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
                     Log.w("Installed Applications",
              rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
                    } 
                    lView.setAdapter(new
  ArrayAdapter(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
              results));
                      }
                  }
  ```

  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5390202)
- :

  ```
  final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent,
         0);
  ```

  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696617)