# нужно синхронизировать количество установленных приложений на телефоне с количеством этих же в моей программе

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, augmented-reality

мне нужна помощь: возникла задача синхронизировать количество установленных приложений на телефоне с количеством этих же приложений в моей программе... То есть это должно выглядеть так: я запускаю мое приложение, и по середине появляется панель с таким количеством кнопок(на которые можно нажать и будет запускаться то приложение, на кнопку которого было произведено нажатие, причем запуск производиться не выходя из моего приложения - как браузер в дополненной реальности на базе плагина Vuplex 3D, причем приложения должны быть только те, которые есть на телефоне) в общем нужно перенести экран смартфона в мое приложение, а точнее - значки приложений которые расположены на рабочем столе моего смартфона...
использую C# + unity 2020.
Возможно ли такое? в интернете открытой информации по этой теме почти нет, может кто-то хотя-бы примерно знает, как это сделать... спасибо заранее:)

Comment: Я правильно понял, что Вам нужно получить список приложений, установленных на устройстве? Для начала - названия и иконки, как я понял

Comment: спасибо за Ваш комментарий!:) да, для начала мне нужно сделать то что Вы сказали... в идеале это должно быть так: я могу запустить свое ПО, и у меня в 3д сцене должны появляться значки вайбера например, инстаграма, ютуба - всех тех приложений что у меня есть на смартфоне, но! если какое-то приложение я удалю, то оно и не будет появляться у меня в приложении... или например что-то скачаю и это приложение у меня автоматически появиться в приложении. Причем я могу нажать на любой значок приложения в моем приложении и будет запускаться то приложение на значок которого было произведено нажатие...

Comment: и это все должно происходить не выходя из моего приложения...

Comment: Касательно списка приложений - вот [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/158496/Список-установленных-программ). Думаю, проблем с переносом на шарпы особых быть не должно. А вот что касается запуска приложений внутри своего... это Вам надо свой лаунчер писать, не факт, что юнити вообще такое умеет

Comment: огромное Вам спасибо! думаю если получилось гугл запустить внутри 3д сцены и работать с ним, то с остальными приложениями тоже получиться!:) еще раз Спасибо!